# Kafka both consumer gets same message withing same group name

Tags: apache-kafka

I have single machine set up for kafka and wanted to run que based kaffa. I have set up group name in consumer.properties like this.

## consumer group id

group.id=test-consumer-group

and when I run 2 consumer both for same topic both gets the message. Is there anything else I need to do other than this?

sudo bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh config/consumer.properties --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic 219Topic --from-beginning

I am using command prompt only no client currently for testing.

Thanks,

Comment: Friendly advice: I think you'll get more traction if you register with your real name and gather some points by helping others.

Comment: Here is how this was resolved in case anyone face this. Used java client to test and started 2 consumer and messages were not duplicated. But then it was flowing through only one consumer. This time the issue was with the following property. I had to set topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms to 0. That means it switches partition after every message.

Comment: check the answer here @Paresh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787843/kafka-consumer-group-id/53788296#53788296