# How to run two console consumers in the same consumer group?

Tags: apache-kafka

When I run two instances of Kafka-console-consumers with the exact same properties (using the default one config/consumer.properties), I get same messages on both the instances.

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server :9092 --topic test1
```

If both the instances have the same consumer group id, shouldn't Kafka send a given message to only one of the consumers? How to run them as one consumer group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From kafka docs i found this

> The default for console consumer's enable.auto.commit property when no group.id is provided is now set to false. This is to avoid polluting the consumer coordinator cache as the auto-generated group is not likely to be used by other consumers.

But here is the trick, use this command to list all consumer groups across all topics, as you said i have opened four console consumers and i want to check list of consumer groups consuming from that topic

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
```

Every console consumer start with different group id, this is the reason always consuming from beginning addition of this property (`--from-beginning`)

```
ups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.
console-consumer-66835
console-consumer-38647
console-consumer-18983
console-consumer-18365
console-consumer-96734
```

Okay easiest way to set  group.id for console consumer

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning --consumer-property group.id=test1
```

Read up [Managing Consumer Groups](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group).

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use `--consumer.config config/consumer.properties` or `--consumer-property group.id=test1` that would specify the `group.id` explicitly.

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --topic test1 \
  --consumer.config config/consumer.properties
```