# kafka console producer sending messages continuously

Tags: apache-kafka, console, producer

I am running Kafka in windows.

I am creating a Kafka console producer with below command

```
C:\kafka_2.11-2.4.0\bin\windows>kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic input-topic
```

and creating kafka console consumer with below command

```
C:\kafka_2.11-2.4.0\bin\windows>kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic input-topic
```

the problem is i am getting the messages continuously. yesterday it was showing only the messages which i am typing to the console producer.

how to stop auto sending messages?

I need to send the messages if I am typing otherwise it should not send blank messages.

Comment: you should get the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787843/how-to-run-two-console-consumers-in-the-same-consumer-group/53788296#53788296

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run two console consumers in the same consumer group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787843/how-to-run-two-console-consumers-in-the-same-consumer-group)

Answer (score 0):

By default, console consumer only gets latest offsets of the topic (only new messages)

If you want to read existing data, you must add `--from-beginning`

If you want to preserve offsets between runs, you need a `--group`

Comment: thanks for your time to spent on the issue and gave the answer.
but what i am looking for is how to stop auto sending messages eventhough i am not typing any message.
I need to send the messages if i am typing otherwise it should not send blank messages.

Comment: `console-producer` always blocks for user-input when sending messages. You can see such in the source code.